# How to invoke a web service call using vbscript

Tags: web-services, vbscript, xmlhttprequest

i am beginner in coding.

I have to call a web service below:
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit

enter a value like 25 and click Invoke returns you the temperature in Fahrenheit.

For that i used below code:

```
url = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit&Celsius=25"
'Set oHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") 'when i use XMLHTTP i am getting error saying "The download of the specified resource has failed."

Set oHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 'If i use it, the response contains Root Element missing

oHttpReq.open "POST", url, False
oHttpReq.send

'Response
responseText = oHttpReq.responseText 

WScript.echo responseText
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19359/Web-Service-Proxy-generator-using-XSLT-targeting-V

Comment: Can some one shed some light on my query. Please let me know where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Create at file.vbs (visual basic script)
Compile with external tool to exe
In server task set this.

```
Const HOST = Sample service in IIS
Const URL = "wsPage.asmx"

Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.open "POST", HOST & URL & "/wsServiceTest", false

'Set the Content-Type header to the specified value
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

' Send the request synchronously
xmlhttp.send "" 
WScript.Echo "Load ok..."
```